# Array inside a mysql_fetch_array. Can't make it work

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

To display some data from a mysql table the usual method that I'm used to is:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
     echo $row['FIELD'];
}
```

Now to make things more dynamic I've tried this:

```
/* $array carries list of column names like 'FIELD'. In this case its the only one
 * $result stores whatever the query like "SELECT * FROM TABLE1" returned
 */
function dosomething($array, $result) 
{
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
     {
          for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array); $i++)     //gets size of $array and loops
          {
              echo $row["'".$array[$i]."'"];         //should read $row['FIELD'] yes?
          }
     }
}
```

The code above shows nothing. Data exists. echo $row['FIELD']; returns something. but the line

```
echo $row["'".$array[$i]."'"];
```

gives nothing in return. I've tried an alternate like-

```
echo $row[$array[$i]];
```

still nothing.

I hope I was able to make the reader understand the problem. How can I put an array in he mysql_fetch_array type array?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I never needed to do such `$row["'".$array[$i]."'"]` in any programming language.

Comment: please dump the $array and write it here.

Comment: Make sure you call the function `dosomething`

Comment: var_dump($array); gives array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "FIELD" } and yes i did call dosomething()

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysql). If you care to learn, [here](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) is a quite good PDO-related tutorial.

Comment: Are you sure the query is returning rows? (check `mysql_num_rows($result)`)

Comment: for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array); $i++) { echo $array[$i]; }....check whether the $array[$i] echo the values correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    foreach ($row as $key => $field)
    {
        echo "$key: $value";
    }
}
```

the fields to display you  have to define in the query
and there is no point in having such a function like your dosomething()

Comment: Yep, the dosomething is pointless as long as he want all the fields to be displayed, but useful if he wants to print out some of them. Of course he can select only the required field on the query level but he may also need to not to display some of the selected fields

Comment: He have to unset them then before filling the template.

Comment: Again, There may also a large number of columns to be unset. The best one is what he is doing right now.

Comment: The "large number of columns to be unset" exists only in your imagination. In the real life this is quite pointless question out of illiterateness.

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

$array=array("table fields"); 
table fielda are id,name,value.
you should put it in array.

```
 $array=array('id','name','value');


 function dosomething($array, $result) 
 {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
        for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array); $i++)     //gets size of $array and loops
        {
            echo $row[$array[$i]];         //should read $row['FIELD'] yes?
         }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Why you use `$row["'".$array[$i]."'"]` this? I think try it `$row["'".$array."'"]`

And make sure array is not empty and call the function

Comment: <?php

 function __autoload($class_name)
 {
     include $class_name.'.php';
 }
 
 $phpmyadmin = new mysql(); //instance of a class that handles mysql connectivity
 $phpmyadmin -> connect('localhost','root','');
 $phpmyadmin -> setdb('DBTEST');
 $result = $phpmyadmin -> runquery("SELECT * FROM TABLE1");
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
 {
   echo $row['FIELD'];
 } 
 $array = array('FIELD');
 dosomething($array,$result);

Comment: /* $array carries list of column names like 'FIELD'. In this case its the only one
  * $result stores whatever the query like "SELECT * FROM TABLE1" returned
  */
 function dosomething($array, $result) 
 {
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
   {
     for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array); $i++)     //gets size of $array and loops
     {
      echo $row["'".$array[$i]."'"];         //should read $row['FIELD'] yes?
     }
   }
 }

?>

Comment: There is a problem with your answer. You do not understand PHP, as well as the poor OP. Why not to learn some first?

Comment: trying to learn by getting stuck. so yeah you are right. and i am learning.